I am getting Memory Error on Merging Data Frames
I have 2 dataframes here as dfA and dfB with the columns as Insertion time and others,and i want the result based on the insertion time with the time delta 10seconds means if time in dfA is 10:00:00 i will need the consolidated data with time of dfB at 10:00:00 and +- 10 seconds. I have written a code here which merges the data then filter the data according to the condition. For less data it is working fine but when the data is large it is giving me an error-:
" MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.83 GiB for an array with shape (3, 82008960) and data type object"
The reference code is below-
from pandas import Timestamp

# Convert `InsertionTime` to datetime
dfA['InsertionTime'] = pd.to_datetime(dfA['InsertionTime'])
dfB['InsertionTime'] = pd.to_datetime(dfB['InsertionTime'])

# Set a tolerance range of ±30 seconds
tolerance = pd.Timedelta(seconds=10)

# Merge using a cartesian product (cross join)
dfA['key'] = 1
dfB['key'] = 1
merged = pd.merge(dfA, dfB, on='key').drop('key', axis=1)

# Filter rows based on the tolerance range
merged['time_diff'] = abs(merged['InsertionTime_x'] - merged['InsertionTime_y'])
consolidated = merged[merged['time_diff'] <= tolerance].drop('time_diff', axis=1)

# Rename columns for clarity
consolidated = consolidated.rename(columns={
    'InsertionTime_x': 'InsertionTime_df1',
    'InsertionTime_y': 'InsertionTime_df2',
    'DeviceName_x': 'DeviceName_df1',
    'DeviceName_y': 'DeviceName_df2',
    'DeviceIP_x': 'DeviceIP_df1',
    'DeviceIP_y': 'DeviceIP_df2',
    'AlarmName_x': 'AlarmName_df1',
    'AlarmName_y': 'AlarmName_df2'
})

is there any way to Handel large data here only otherwise i been thinking to put this data in database and from the queries extract the required data. Can we do it here in chunks?
Please let me know.

You're most likely looking for a merge_asof. Please provide a [mre] of your inputs for explicitness.

You should use a more memory-efficient method such as merge_asof to do this. Here is an example:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

n = 100000
start_time = pd.Timestamp('2023-08-01 10:00:00')
time_increment = pd.to_timedelta(np.random.randint(0, 30, size=n), unit='S')
dfA = pd.DataFrame({
    'InsertionTime': start_time + np.cumsum(time_increment),
    'DeviceName': np.random.choice(['DeviceA1', 'DeviceA2', 'DeviceA3', 'DeviceA4', 'DeviceA5'], size=n),
    'DeviceIP': np.random.choice(['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.3', '192.168.1.4', '192.168.1.5'], size=n),
    'AlarmName': np.random.choice(['AlarmA1', 'AlarmA2', 'AlarmA3', 'AlarmA4', 'AlarmA5'], size=n)
})

time_increment = pd.to_timedelta(np.random.randint(0, 30, size=n), unit='S')
dfB = pd.DataFrame({
    'InsertionTime': start_time + np.cumsum(time_increment),
    'DeviceName': np.random.choice(['DeviceB1', 'DeviceB2', 'DeviceB3', 'DeviceB4', 'DeviceB5'], size=n),
    'DeviceIP': np.random.choice(['192.168.2.1', '192.168.2.2', '192.168.2.3', '192.168.2.4', '192.168.2.5'], size=n),
    'AlarmName': np.random.choice(['AlarmB1', 'AlarmB2', 'AlarmB3', 'AlarmB4', 'AlarmB5'], size=n)
})

dfA['InsertionTime'] = pd.to_datetime(dfA['InsertionTime'])
dfB['InsertionTime'] = pd.to_datetime(dfB['InsertionTime'])
dfA = dfA.sort_values('InsertionTime')
dfB = dfB.sort_values('InsertionTime')

tolerance = pd.Timedelta(seconds=10)

start = time.time()

merged = pd.merge_asof(dfA, dfB, on='InsertionTime', direction='nearest', tolerance=tolerance)

consolidated = merged.dropna(subset=['DeviceName_y'])

consolidated = consolidated.rename(columns={
    'InsertionTime': 'InsertionTime',
    'DeviceName_x': 'DeviceName_df1',
    'DeviceName_y': 'DeviceName_df2',
    'DeviceIP_x': 'DeviceIP_df1',
    'DeviceIP_y': 'DeviceIP_df2',
    'AlarmName_x': 'AlarmName_df1',
    'AlarmName_y': 'AlarmName_df2'
})

end = time.time()

print(consolidated)
print(f"Time taken for merging: {end - start} seconds")

which gives
            InsertionTime DeviceName_df1 DeviceIP_df1 AlarmName_df1  \
0     2023-08-01 10:00:01       DeviceA3  192.168.1.5       AlarmA5   
1     2023-08-01 10:00:19       DeviceA2  192.168.1.5       AlarmA5   
2     2023-08-01 10:00:34       DeviceA3  192.168.1.2       AlarmA3   
3     2023-08-01 10:00:58       DeviceA3  192.168.1.5       AlarmA3   
4     2023-08-01 10:01:15       DeviceA4  192.168.1.1       AlarmA1   
...                   ...            ...          ...           ...   
99858 2023-08-18 05:29:38       DeviceA5  192.168.1.5       AlarmA3   
99859 2023-08-18 05:29:39       DeviceA4  192.168.1.2       AlarmA2   
99860 2023-08-18 05:29:57       DeviceA5  192.168.1.1       AlarmA1   
99861 2023-08-18 05:30:05       DeviceA3  192.168.1.3       AlarmA3   
99862 2023-08-18 05:30:17       DeviceA2  192.168.1.2       AlarmA2   

      DeviceName_df2 DeviceIP_df2 AlarmName_df2  
0           DeviceB3  192.168.2.5       AlarmB4  
1           DeviceB5  192.168.2.5       AlarmB5  
2           DeviceB5  192.168.2.1       AlarmB4  
3           DeviceB5  192.168.2.3       AlarmB3  
4           DeviceB4  192.168.2.1       AlarmB3  
...              ...          ...           ...  
99858       DeviceB1  192.168.2.3       AlarmB1  
99859       DeviceB1  192.168.2.3       AlarmB1  
99860       DeviceB2  192.168.2.4       AlarmB4  
99861       DeviceB5  192.168.2.3       AlarmB3  
99862       DeviceB5  192.168.2.3       AlarmB3  

[91600 rows x 7 columns]

with
Time taken for merging: 0.06485986709594727 seconds

